# How do you create subdomains using PHP? Is is possible on shared hosting?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, php, subdomain

I'm interested to create subdomains on the fly directly from php. For example when an user create a new page I want that page to be newpage.mydomain.com. Is that possible without changing the php or apache configuration files (supposing I'm using a shared hosting account).

Later Edit: I'm talking about my domain, and I have full access to the domain administration area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set up an error document in your .htaccess file that redirects every single 404 to a file called maybe redirection.php. This .php file is what will handle the "on the fly" redirects.
2. Add a wildcard DNS record in your zone files, so that [whateverhere].yourdomain.com points to the IP of your webserver
3. Add a wildcard serveralias in your apache configs by using:
   ServerAlias *.yourdomain.com
4. Write the following code in your redirection.php file.

.

```
<?php

$url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URL"];
$newurl=str_replace(".yourdomain.com","",$url);
$newcomplete="http://yourdomain.com/".$newurl;
Header("Location: ".$newcomplete);

?>
```

Does this help a bit?

Comment: This may work on shared hosting, if your provider will allow you to setup a "catch all" for your webserver. Contact the hosting provider.

Comment: The redirection is really required? I can directly analyze the request url and build the page accordingly I assume.

Comment: Well then you can take that approach, but you would still need a wildcard DNS entry, and apache needs to know how to respond to the fake subdomain name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this. 
You need to make sure that first you set up a wildcard * A record against your domain in your domain register DN panel.

Once you have set up the wildcard, you can just look at the >

```
 $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not possible through php alone. and I don't think shared hosting allow that.
anyway, for that you have to own a domain (or have permission to edit DNS record) then you can add wildcard record to allow any subdomain to point to a single machine (identified by its IP adress)

edit (from  Powerlord comment)

apache have to redirect each subdomain to the same vhost
usually with `ServerAlias *.example.com` in a vhost configuration

/edit

then in php you can check which from subdomain the page is request by parsing(spliting) `$_SERVER['HOST_NAME']`

eg:

```
$host = explode ('.', $_SERVER['HOST_NAME']);
array_pop ($host);
array_pop ($host);
$subdomain = join ('.', $host);
```

Comment: This is wrong. I do exactly what the OP is requesting on THOUSANDS of pages.

Comment: @Laykes: It really depends on how your host has things configured.  By default, Apache (which the OP is asking about) does **not** let you do this; instead it falls back to the `_default_` virtual host, and failing that, the main server configuration.

Comment: how is that wrong? 
I explain, which right you need to do that and express that >I< don't think there is a shared hosting service which allow that.

does it deserve a -1? 
maybe a better comment would have been to link to a hosting service that provide that.